# Delphi ntextcat - how to implement

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-2007

I am trying to access ntextcat dll from Delphi 2007.

Registering the dll´s failed (I have tried 32 and 64Bit regsvr32).
Importing the typelibrary in Delphi failed as well (as .dll and .Net).

Is there anybody out there who got access to ntextcat within Delphi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a .net library. As such it is not readily accessible from unmanaged code such as Delphi. If you do want to consume it from Delphi you'll need to create a wrapper. For instance by using one of the following:

- A COM interface.
- A mixed mode C++/CLI assembly that wraps the managed library and exposes an unmanaged interface.
- A wrapper based on Robert Giesecke's UnmanagedExports.

The latter two allow you to consume a .net assembly as a native DLL.

If the library has a rich and broad interface then the task of wrapping it if not going to be terribly easy or convenient. You may be better finding a different library that is easier to consume.

If the library has a small interface, or if you only need a small part of its capabilities, then making a wrapper may be more tractable.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your reply. I have checked Delphi XE2 in the meantime. It found the option "Import component" -> "import .NET-Assembly". But this does not working either. Maybe it is easier to wrap the .net library within a small C# dll...

Comment: The easiest is going to be UnmanagedExports. You just want to supply some text and have a list of candidate langs returned. That's probably a single call. Use WideString on the Delphi side. UnmanagedType.BStr on the managed side. About 15 minutes work if you've done it before but you may need to do quite a bit of learning first!

Comment: FWIW: There's a [C library](http://software.wise-guys.nl/libtextcat/docs.html). As David wrote that might be an easier road.

Comment: OK, I will give it a try :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on David´s answer (thank you for pointing me in the right direction) this the solution using Robert Giesecke's UnmanagedExports:

C# (be aware to set the platform target to the same as your Delphi application targets to! Do not use "AnyTarget"!)

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
       [DllExport("testfunc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
       public static int anytest(int iInt) {
          return iInt;
       }
    }
}
```

The Delphi source:

```
Type
   Ttest = function(const iInt: Integer): Integer; stdcall;

procedure TForm1.btTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   Handle: Integer;
   test  : Ttest;
begin
   Handle := LoadLibrary(<PathToDLL>ClassLibrary1.dll');

   if Handle <> 0 then begin
      @test := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'testfunc');
      if @test <> NIL then ShowMessage(IntToStr(test(1234)));
   end;
end;
```

Based on this it is possible to access the ntextcat .net library.